# ionic2: menuToggle button align to right automatically

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to set menuToggle button in the left side of input text I used this code:

```
<div id="searchDiv">
        <ion-item>
            <button item-start ion-button icon-only color="dark" menuToggle>
                <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <input type="text" placeholder="I'm Searching For .." [(ngModel)]="searchInput" />
        </ion-item>
    </div>
```

and I get this output:
[image: the output with menuToggle in tag <button>]

If I remove menuToggle from tag button to be:

```
<button item-start ion-button icon-only color="dark" menuToggle>
   <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

It align to left correctly, I don't know what is the problem with menuToggle, what should i do?

Answer (score 3):

In `src\app\app.html` set this:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side='right'>
```

This will work correctly.

if you want menu toggle at right side then do it and this will be at your page

```
<div class="bar bar-header"> <h1 class="title">Header Buttons</h1> <button item-start ion-button icon-only color="dark" menuToggle> <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon> </button> </div>
```

use this code for buttons

Comment: It doesn't, the menuToggle button in other pages is aligned correctly, It align to right only in the above case!!

Comment: if you want menu toggle at right side then do it
and
"<div class="bar bar-header">
  
  <h1 class="title">Header Buttons</h1>
  <button item-start ion-button icon-only color="dark" menuToggle>
   <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
</button>

</div>"
use this code for buttons

Comment: ya that is help full